# Google Calendar In Asp.net C#

Tags: c#

I want to make event calendar in my web application.

I use this example but it return error wheni i execute it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201907/Using-Google-Calendar-in-an-ASP-NET-Website

```
ERROR IS GIVEN BELOW
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'GetCalendarID' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 11:     <div>
Line 12: 
Line 13:     <iframe name="a" src="https://www.Google.com/calendar/embed?src=<%=GetCalendarID()%>&ctz=Europe%2FMoscow" 
Line 14:             style="border: 0" width="800"
Line 15: height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="Test">
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can any one help me Please?

or if you have better solving then tell me

Regards,
Mehmood Alvi

Comment: Do you have GetCalendarID() method in your code-behind file? ... and in the right casing?

Comment: That `GetCalendarID()` looks like a call to a method in the code-behind. Does it exist there? Some more of your code (aspx + aspx.cs) would help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `GetCalendarID()` (which would more idiomatically be a property, of course) directly from your page - not on an instance of the `GoogleCalendar` class. Unless you've added all the `GoogleCalendar` code from CodeProject directly into your page, you need to first create an instance of `GoogleCalendar` in your code-behind and provide some way of accessing it, e.g. as a member variable:

```
<%=calendar.GetCalendarID()%>
```

Fundamentally, the problem is as simple as the compiler's explained it to be: it can't find a method called `GetCalendarID` in the context it's got, which is the page. The *exact* best solution will depend on what else you're doing - the above is just an idea.

Answer (score -1):

You should first call the method `SaveCalendarIdAndUrl()` cause thats where the `m_CalendarId`; gets filled before it can be used by the method `GetCalendarID()`